# Ie11 causing issue with my site

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11

Hi all I have made a website that I am having real issues with, on all browsers I have looked at but ie11

The website is www.rebelrunnersmedway.co.uk

On ie11 the paragraphs are coming up in columns but not on any other browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has a `column-count` style applied to `@media only screen and (min-width:38em) #content p`

Taking a quick look at the [multicolumn caniuse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), it looks like it's only showing in IE because all other browsers (other than Opera Mini) require the use of a vendor-specific prefix.

If you want the columns to appear everywhere, change the rule to be:

```
/*@media only screen and (min-width:38em)*/
#content p {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
}
```

If you don't want the columns, simply remove the `column-count` attribute.

Comment: Legend thanks didn't realise I put that in there well done thank you !

Comment: Because I am on mac I cannot or have not been able to find a way to test ie so missed this

Comment: @JonFuller There are actually free, official, VMs available for OSX to run Windows with versions of IE down to 6. They are available at: https://www.modern.ie/en-gb/virtualization-tools

Comment: Nice thanks great help

Comment: Is it hard to install ?

Comment: @JonFuller - I believe it simply requires VirtualBox or VMWare